# Can Hadoop distinguish different salve nodes and designate each node to handle different data?

Tags: hadoop

I need something like this:

For example, there are three files required as mapper input: file01, file02 and file03.
There are also three files as configuration parameters stored in the local disk: r1, r2 and r3.

The mapper program firstly handles r1, r2 and r3 and generate three different program instances p1, p2 and p3(the same processing algorithm, but with different parameters, so the different instances).

What I want is that **p1 only handles file01, p2 only handles file02 and p3 only handles file03**. namely, three slave nodes are handled in the same way but different input and output, could it?

Why I need this?  because r1, r2 and r3 instances are very large, if combined into one instance, computing is too slow. To my knowledge, this demand can not be achieved on Hadoop, because the mapper input files seem to be indistinguishable. Any ideas about this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: [MultipleInputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleInputs.html)?

Comment: Yes, different input has different program instance to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [MultipleInputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleInputs.html) is the perfect class to handle this. Basically it allows you to have different mappers process different data (you can also specify a different input formats).

The syntax is :
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,inputPath,SequenceFileInputFormat.class,MyMapper.class);
//you don't need to specify the mapper if they all use the same mapper